# Is it possible to search for a spring bean by it's type in Intellij Ultimate

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ Ultimate there is a tab at the bottom that shows a list of beans in application

[image]

When I type something it filters the list of beans by name of the method annotated with `@Bean` that creates the bean or by class if it is a `@Component`.

Is it possible to search all beans that implement some type? In my case I want to see all beans that are `feign.Feign.Builder`   but if I enter it to this search the list is empty even if the bean exists.

Comment: `Is it possible to search all beans that implement some type?` You can find all implementations of the interface via Main menu | Navigate | **Go to Implementation(s)** action on that interface/class. Doesn't it help?

Comment: Not always. I have to find a bean that is created by Spring somewhere, for example `feign.Feign.Builder`, it is not in my code, the idea is to look for a current implementation

Comment: Feel free to file a request at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA